# Dismiss a number pad-style keyboard without adding Done key

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

There is no <kbd>Done</kbd> button on a Number Pad-type keyboard. I don't want to add a custom <kbd>Done</kbd> button, but how do I dismiss the keyboard?

Comment: Do you want to use a toolbar ?

Comment: yes but it should be compatible to ios 3.1.3 as well.

Comment: Do you want to dismiss it when you touch the view ? You can set the view as UIControl, and make the numpad dismiss ?.. Well.. normal way to do this would be to have a `UIToolBar`, or a Done Button inside the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a *UINavigationBar/UIToolBar* with a done button(a *UIBarButtonItem*), and make the textField/textView *resignFirstResponder* on the done button's action.

You can add the *UINavigationBar/UIToolBar* as **inputAccessoryView** of textField/textView.

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = aNavBarWithDoneButton;
```

***Edit:** Availability iOS (3.2 and later)*

Comment: can i add or attach that toolbar with keyboard?

Comment: Yes. It is introduced in iOS 3.2. It won't work in lower versions.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to add a new button somewhere in your UI that calls `resignFirstResponder` on your `UITextField` (or whatever) when tapped. Putting this in a toolbar is problematic on iPhone because toolbars are typically at the bottom of the screen and obscured by the keyboard.

A slightly more complex solution is to put an invisible `UIView` behind all of your other tappable UI elements. Any taps not handled by your existing UI will go to this new view, which can call `resignFirstResponder` on your text field.

If neither of these sound appealing, perhaps you should expand your question to include the type of behavior you want.