# Resigning Number Pad of TextField ios

Tags: ios, numbers, textfield, resignfirstresponder, numpad

I am using the keyboard type Number Pad for a particular Text Field which is to be given with a zip number. When using regular keyboard i use resignfirstresponder to quit the keyboard when i click on the enter key in that keyboard. But for the number pad, other than numbers there is only a backspace key. So is there a way to customize it or some other technique to resign the number pad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of answers are available for this question.

Use [dismissing Number Pad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127104/dismissing-number-pad) or [How to dismiss number pad keyboard by tapping anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991085/how-to-dismiss-number-pad-keyboard-by-tapping-anywhere)

You can implement which way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991085/how-to-dismiss-number-pad-keyboard-by-tapping-anywhere)t for hiding the number pad when tapping on your view or you may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679637/dismiss-a-number-pad-style-keyboard-without-adding-done-key) for another solution by adding done button on UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways to do this:

1. As soon as u show the numPad, add a 'Done' button on tha navigationBar on tap of which you resign the keyboard and remove this 'Done' button from Navigation Bar.
2. Add a toolBar on top of keyboard for a NumberPad and add a Done button on top of this toolbar. Set the origin of this toolBar (0,maxScreenheight), and  on display of the keyboard, change the origin of this toolbar to (0, maxScreenHeight-keyboardHeight-ToolBarHeight) with animationDuration of 0.3. On dismiss of the keyboard change the origin of the toolBar back to (0,maxScreenheight). by doing this the toolbar will look like a part of the keyboard as the animaion duration of the keyboard is 0.3.

Comment: I am interested in your second solution in SWIFT, do you know if there is a git or something for this ? I can create a question on this if you have a good solution - thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do so when user touch the screen anywhere the keyboard will dismiss.Here is the code:-

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [yourtextFieldName resignFirstResponder];// This will dismiss your keyBoard.
}
```

and must call UITextField Delegate.
If you want to customise the keyboard here is the link which can help you out:-

http://code4app.net/category/keyboard

Hope this will help you out.